# Calls to the web service will fail unless the Silverlight project is hosted in the same project

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, web-services

I am opening some older demo code and received the following message when I started a debugging session:

```
"The Silverlight project you are about to debug uses web services.  Calls to the 
web service will fail unless the silverlight project is hosted in and launched 
from the same web project that contains the web services."
```

I am working in Visual Studio 2010, and the projects are configured for .NET 4.0.  There is a web project which hosts the xap file and a Silverlight project which builds the xap.  The Silverlight project has a service reference to a publicly available stock quote service.

My question: What does the above warning mean (in layman's terms) and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this will go away if you set the web project which hosts the Silverlight application to be your startup project (right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Set as Startup Project").

Comment: ran into this problem again, and apparently I already had this problem cause I up-voted it already. I wish I could up-vote it again

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight by default can only make calls either to services hosted on the same domain where the XAP was downloaded, or to services which explicitly allow callers from other domains to make this call - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx for more information on that. Since you say you're calling a publicly available service (I'm assuming you don't own it), then either the calls will just work (if the service allows cross-domain calls), or they will fail (if it doesn't).

Comment: One more thing, if the service doesn't allow cross-domain calls, you may create some service in the same domain to *proxy* the calls to the service, since the service itself won't be subject to the same x-domain restrictions as the SL application.